# Python - filter list of dicts by top value in key

Tags: python

I'm trying to narrow down list of dicts by filtering it by value in one of the keys.

Current codes does it but I don't know how to retain entire dictionary rather then only those fields I filter by.

```
final_list = []

jobs = [glue_client.job_status(e) for e in j]

for e in jobs:
    for page in e:
        final_list.append(page["JobRuns"])
            
flat_list = [item for sublist in final_list for item in sublist]
sorted_list = sorted(flat_list, key=lambda k: (k['JobName'], k['StartedOn']), reverse=True)

#need to have following keys: "JobName", "JobRunState", "StartedOn" and "Id"
latest_jobs = [
                {'JobName': key, 'StartedOn': max(item['StartedOn'] for item in values)}
                for key, values in groupby(flat_list, lambda dct: dct['JobName'])
        ]


print(latest_jobs)
```

Data at `sorted_list` variable looks as below:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'JobName': 'a', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'JobRunState': 'fail', 'id': 'xyz'},
    {'JobName': 'a', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'JobRunState': 'ok', 'id': 'xyz'},
    {'JobName': 'b', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'JobRunState': 'fail', 'id': 'xyz'},
    {'JobName': 'a', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'JobRunState': 'fai;', 'id': 'xyz'},
    {'JobName': 'b', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'JobRunState': 'ok', 'id': 'xyz'}
]
```

Expected output:

```
filtered_list = [
    {'JobName': 'a', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'JobRunState': 'fail', 'id': 'xyz'},
    {'JobName': 'b', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'JobRunState': 'fail', 'id': 'xyz'}
]
```

Comment: Just for clarification. Is that the gotten output from your code or the wanted output?

Comment: How is this not just `filtered_list = [x for x in list_of_dicts if x['StartedOn'].year == 2022]`?

Comment: I need to have `top 1` (latest) dict for each `JobNam`. `filtered_list` doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some judicious use of `itertools.groupby`, `sorted`, and `max`.

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'JobName': 'a', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000), 'JobRunState': 'fail', 'id': 'xyz'},
    {'JobName': 'a', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000), 'JobRunState': 'ok', 'id': 'xyz'},
    {'JobName': 'b', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000), 'JobRunState': 'fail', 'id': 'xyz'},
    {'JobName': 'a', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000), 'JobRunState': 'fai;', 'id': 'xyz'},
    {'JobName': 'b', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000), 'JobRunState': 'ok', 'id': 'xyz'}
]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = sorted(list_of_dicts, key=itemgetter('JobName'))

[max(jobs, key=itemgetter('StartedOn')) 
 for jn, jobs in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter('JobName'))]
# [{'JobName': 'a', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000), 'JobRunState': 'fail', 'id': 'xyz'}, 
#  {'JobName': 'b', 'StartedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 18, 13, 0, 47, 306000), 'JobRunState': 'fail', 'id': 'xyz'}]
```